# What is the fully qualified name of a friend function defined inside of a class?

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend, name-lookup, fully-qualified-naming

What is the fully qualified name of a friend function defined inside of a class?

I recently saw an example analogous to the following. What is the fully qualified name of `val()` below?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    class A {
        int x;
    public:
        A(int x = 0) : x(x) { }

        friend int val(const A &a) { return a.x; }
    };
}

int main() {
    foo::A a(42);

    // val() found using ADL:
    std::cout << val(a) << std::endl;

    // foo::val(a); // error: 'val' is not a member of 'foo'
    // foo::A::val(a); // error: 'val' is not a member of 'foo::A'

    return 0;   
}
```

Is argument-dependent lookup the only way `val()` can be found?

Admittedly, this does not stem from a practical problem. I am simply looking to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is argument-dependent lookup the only way val() can be found?

Yes, it is the only way. To quote the holy standard at [[namespace.memdef]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#3):

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified lookup.

So while `val` is a member of `foo`, it's not visible to lookup from the friend declaration alone. An out of class definition (which is also a declaration) is required to make it visible. For an inline definition (and no out-of-class declaration) it means ADL is the only way to call the function.

---

As an added bonus, C++ did once have a concept of "friend name injection". That however has been removed, and the rules for ADL adjusted as a replacement. A more detailed overview can be found in WG21 paper [N0777](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: "So while `val` is a member of `foo`" <- So this is a situation where `val` is indeed a member of `foo`, but `foo::val` cannot be used to refer to it. That is important because I just managed to get the compiler to issue an error message where it refers to `val`, and it said `foo::val`.  That was confusing given that earlier it said that `val` was not a member of `foo`.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Yup. I'm looking for the context that caused this somewhat strange rule to exit. Hoping to present it too.

Comment: An out of class declaration with an inline definition works too

Comment: @PasserBy - Thanks! I've never actually seen anyone do that, so I didn't know.

Comment: @PasserBy: can you please elaborate on this? Do you mean, that `val` is still a member of `foo`, but declared out of class somehow? What's the syntax of this?

Comment: @geza - Passer By meant something like [this](https://ideone.com/VIgEEQ).

Comment: @StoryTeller: thanks! I misunderstood what you say, I thought that you're talking about `val` is a member of `A`. (I thought that `foo` is the class, it was an oversight)

Comment: @Szabolcs - Found the paper in question.

Comment: So, as weird as this looked to me at first, it's actually a good thing to be able to have a function that can only be looked up in this manner.

Answer (score 7):

**C++ Standard [7.3.1.2/3 (of ISO/IEC 14882:2011)]:**

> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace. **If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares
>   a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the
>   innermost enclosing namespace.** **The name of the friend is not found by
>   unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3) until a
>   matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (either
>   before or after the class definition granting friendship)**. If a friend
>   function is called, its name may be found by the name lookup that
>   considers functions from namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the function arguments (3.4.2). If the name in a friend
>   declaration is neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration
>   is a function or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine
>   whether the entity has been previously declared **shall not consider any
>   scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace**.