# How can I make friend function template of a class template visible in the namespace scope?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend-function

I would like to make the example below compile. I have a class template which defines a friend function template, but it's not visible in the surrounding namespace by default.

```cpp
namespace ns {
template<typename T> struct Foo {  // Class template.
    template<typename U> friend void bar(Foo, Foo<U> f) {  // Friend function template, defined inline.
        static_cast<void>(f.private_field);  // Should only compile when T=U.
    }
private:
    int private_field{};
};
}

int main() {
    bar(ns::Foo<char>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});      // Ok.
    ns::bar(ns::Foo<char>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});  // (1) FIXME: `ns::bar` not found.
    //bar(ns::Foo<bool>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});    // (2): Should fail because bar() here is not a friend of Foo<char>.
}
```

I would like to be able to call `ns::bar<int>(ns::Foo<char>{})` (`(1)` should compile) while not declaring any friendship between `bar` call and unrelated `Foo<char>` at `(2)`. **How do I make this happen?**

If `Foo` was a non-template, I would declare `template<typename U> void bar(Foo, Foo);` in `namespace ns`.

If `bar` was a non-template (e.g. with `U=char` fixed), I would declare it as a template function outside the class and befriend its full specialization, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18792618/767632): `friend void bar<T>(Foo, Foo<char> f);`.

However, both are templates and I'm out of ideas.

UPD: I've tried giving the same trick as with non-template `bar` and make it a template outside of the class. However, it looks like befriending a partial specialization is not possible.

My attempt:

```cpp
namespace ns {
template<typename T> struct Foo;

template<typename U, typename T> void bar(Foo<T>, Foo<U>);

template<typename T> struct Foo {
    template<typename U> friend void bar<U, T>(Foo, Foo<U> f);
    // template<typename U, typename TT> friend void bar(Foo<TT>, Foo<U> f);  // Compiles, but gives extra friendship to `bar`.
private:
    int private_field{};
};

template<typename U, typename T> void bar(Foo<T>, Foo<U> f) {
    static_cast<void>(f.private_field);  // Should only compile when T=U.
}
}

int main() {
    bar(ns::Foo<char>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});      // Ok.
    ns::bar(ns::Foo<char>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});  // (1) FIXME: `ns::bar` not found.
    //bar(ns::Foo<bool>{}, ns::Foo<char>{});    // (2): Should fail because bar() here is not a friend of Foo<char>.
}
```

GCC's output:

```
x.cpp:7:38: error: invalid use of template-id 'bar<U, T>' in declaration of primary template
    7 |     template<typename U> friend void bar<U, T>(Foo, Foo<U> f);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~
x.cpp: In instantiation of 'void ns::bar(ns::Foo<T>, ns::Foo<U>) [with U = char; T = char]':
x.cpp:19:41:   required from here
x.cpp:14:25: error: 'int ns::Foo<char>::private_field' is private within this context
   14 |     static_cast<void>(f.private_field);  // Should only compile when T=U.
      |                       ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
x.cpp:10:9: note: declared private here
   10 |     int private_field{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unsalvigable without a bridge function because of template ids etc. In your first approach, all your inner `bar`s are:

*for every `T` in `Foo<T>`*:

```cpp
template<typename U>
void bar(Foo<T>, Foo<U>);
```

so every `Foo<T>` produces it's own *independant template overload* of `bar`.  That works for ADL, but does not work for qualified lookup, since friend declaration does not inject it's name into the namespace, see [N0777](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf) from 1995. It's fully disqussed in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136153).

Adding one shared declaration like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
void bar(Foo<T>, Foo<U>);
```

would not work, because this template id is different from above. It compiles, but yields linkage errors (because `t<T, U> bar(Foo<T>, Foo<U>)` is not defined anywhere).

Your second approach has a similar problem: your code tried to define a new function because of it's template id and fails to do that (hence `invalid use of template-id in declaration of primary template`).

Your third attempt actually declared a friend specialization of `bar` (and you have exactly 1 template-id), but as you state, it gives away too much.

I you really want to pursue incapsulation, I would recommend using a bridge function with separate template id:

```
namespace ns {

    template<typename T> struct Foo {
        template<typename U> friend void bar_(Foo<T>, Foo<U> f) { // bar_ here
            static_cast<void>(f.private_field);
        }
    private:
        int private_field{};
    };

    template<typename T, typename U> void bar(Foo<T> x, Foo<U> f) { // end user gets a good name
        bar_(x, f); // ADL overload resolution, goes looking for friends and such.
    }

}
```

Also adding some type-dispatching arguments while keeping name `bar` should work too.